# where $x^{\cos x}$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I was dealing with the function $f(x)= x^{\cos x}$.

I can not figure out where this function is defined and where this function will be differentiable.

What is the derivative of $f(x)$ ?

Can anyone please help me ?

**My Attempt**: $f(x)$ is clearly differentiable on $(0 , \infty)$. $f'(x) = x^{\cos x }(-x\sin x  + \frac{\cos x}{x})$ when $x>0$.

Comment: This might help: $x^{\cos x}=e^{\cos(x)\ln(x)}$

Comment: What else are you struggling with? You can't even define it for $x < 0$ in a meaningful way.

Comment: So you are saying $f(x)$ is not defined in $(- \infty , 0)$. Can you please tell why ?@MichaelBarz

Comment: @MichaelBarz for which values of $x$ does the right hand side of the equation $x^{\cos x}=e^{\cos(x)\ln(x)}$ make sense?

Comment: @sani Because in general, it does not make much sense to raise a negative number to a non-integral power, so unless you want to do something sorta silly like defining it on the negative number on an isolated set of points where $\cos x$ is an integer, it's best to not define it there.

Comment: We should not escape. We should further investigate and try to come up with a concrete result.@MichaelBarz

Comment: just because it seems complicated , we can not give up.@MichaelBarz

Comment: Well, sani, start with something simpler, like defining $y=(-1)^x$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Okay. Tell me how would you like to proceed .@GerryMyerson

Comment: @sani: Why don't you use Gerry's hint to try to work some things out on your own?

Comment: @sani: Unless you are willing to use complex numbers, the function $x^y$ does not have a meaningful definition if $x<0$, unless $y$ is a rational number with odd denominator.

Comment: First, sani, you say "we can not give up," then you ask how I would proceed. Sounds like you gave up!